# SQL - SELECTING from one table while INNER JOINING between two others (many-to-many table and another table)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, inner-join

I am a beginner to Web programming and SQL. I am not used to work with tables that have a many to many relationship and I am facing a problem here due to my lack of knowledge.

Those are my tables and this is what I want to do:

Table users

```
ID | Users
-----------------
1  | John
2  | Mark
3  | Sophia
```

Table projects

```
ID | Projects
-----------------
1  | Generic Name nº 1
2  | Generic Name nº 2
3  | Generic Name nº 3
```

Table users_projects

```
UsersID | ProjectsID
-----------------
    1   |    1
    2   |    1
    2   |    2
    3   |    2
    3   |    3
```

I want to select all the users where, let's say, the Projects.Id value is 1, while keeping the many to many realtionship between this two tables. How do I do that?

Desired Output

```
ID | Users
-----------------
1  | John
2  | Mark
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (as text table)

Comment: The table projects is not used in your desired output so why mention it?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM users t1
JOIN users_projects t2 ON t1.id = t2.usersid
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM users_projects t2 
               WHERE t1.id = t2.usersid )
```

---

I recommend you to rename `ID` columns in `users` and `projects` and assign them the same names which are used in `users_projects`. This will remove ambiguity and will make your structure and queries more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below, by using left join you specify on which fields to join.
You can use table aliases and prefix the fields with the alias to indicate between which table the fields are linked.

```
select u.Users, u.ID, p.Projects, p.ID
from Users u
left join user_project up
on u.ID = up.UsersID
left join projects p
on up.ProjectsID = p.projects
order by u.Users, p.Projects
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN does not provide the selection of matched rows only. Your query's output does not match desired one.

Comment: There is no need for left join and table projects it is not needed

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result for `Projects.Id value is 1` try:

```
select u.ID,u.Users
from users u
inner join users_projects p on u.ID=p.UsersID
where p.ProjectsID=1;



CREATE TABLE  users (
 ID int,
 Users varchar(10) );

INSERT INTO users VALUES
(1,'John'),
(2,'Mark'),
(3,'Sophia');

CREATE TABLE  users_projects (
 UsersID int,
 ProjectsID int );

INSERT INTO users_projects VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(3,2),
(3,3);
```

Result:

```
ID  Users
1   John
2   Mark
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=463a1cfac69f07d41a2caa440decdb25